# Scoped Model - Receiver: Closure: ({dynamic formData}) => void from Function 'login'

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to implement ScopedModel, I have code example works like this without any problem but when I try to implement the same algorithm I'm getting the error. Here the things you need:

Login button code block:

```
void _submitForm(Function authenticate) async {
    _formKey.currentState.save();
    print(_formData);
    http.Response response = await authenticate(_formData);
  }
```

scoped model login code block:

```
void login({Map<String, dynamic> formData}) async {
    http.Response response = await http.post(
      url,
      body: formData,
    );
    print(response.body);
  }
```

onPressed code:

```
onPressed: () => _submitForm(model.login),
```

Error:

```
NoSuchMethodError: Closure call with mismatched arguments: function '_MainModel&Model&ConnectedModel&AuthModel.login'
E/flutter (13496): Receiver: Closure: ({dynamic formData}) => void from Function 'login':.
E/flutter (13496): Tried calling: _MainModel&Model&ConnectedModel&AuthModel.login(_LinkedHashMap len:3)
E/flutter (13496): Found: _MainModel&Model&ConnectedModel&AuthModel.login({dynamic formData}) => void
```

I tried to change type of methods etc. Nothing worked properly.

I'm open to different style of implementations via Scoped Model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you're passing in a function that takes a parameter to a method that expects a function that takes no parameters.

Try this:

```
void _submitForm(Function(Map<String, dynamic>) authenticate) async {
  _formKey.currentState.save();
  print(_formData);
  http.Response response = await authenticate(_formData);
}
```

I may be wrong but I don't think you can pass around functions that contain named parameters, so your scoped model code would need to be:

```
void login(Map<String, dynamic> formData) async {
  http.Response response = await http.post(
    url,
    body: formData,
  );
  print(response.body);
}
```

Comment: Named parameters are the problem. Thank you! You don't need to specify Function(data type), just Function is working.